# UIWebView download it's image content

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, highcharts

I'm using [high charts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to draw charts in a native iOS application in a web view
the problem is when I export the chart as image, the image appears in the web view and I can't save it or download it.

in the desktop browser, when I export it, it immediately start downloading.

the exporting mechanism is provided via a JS function call, I call it from the native application using

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"chart.exportChart({ type: 'image/jpeg', filename: 'chart'});"]);
```

I made a dig into the JS library and I found that they send a post request to there server to get the image, so I don't have a URL for the image I can download it with!!

I want to be able to save the image and pass it to my native application, any help!!

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is converting your web view into an image. The following snippet does it:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.bounds.size);
[webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I want to use the JS functions, because they provide exporting with lot of formats, png, jpg, pdf and I'm going to add excel